# How do I get a list of unique values and the number of occurences from SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, count, aggregate-functions

I have a SQL Server 2008 database with millions of records. One field has values ranging from 0 to 250 and may, or may not, include all numbers witin the range. How do I query the database to get a list of distinct values and the number of records contaiing that value?

I used a Select Count(Distinct) query but that only gives me the number of distinct values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to use the [GROUP BY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx) clause:

```
SELECT
  column1,
  COUNT(*)
FROM
  table
GROUP BY column1
```

Comment: +1: You were first.  To the OP: Any column not wrapped in an aggregate function (IE: COUNT, MAX, MIN...) needs to be specified in the GROUP BY clause.  Only MySQL & SQLite don't require this, and their behavior is non-standard.

Comment: After I posted the question I thought the solution may involve GROUP BY but didn't see how to tie it together. Thanks!